# WPF Set property of element in Style (Visual.Brush)

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set the `Content` property of the Label (`L_Watermark`)?
I tried different ways but nothing work.
Normally to set a property of an element about his name but here it doesn´t work.
I want do do it in the CodeBehind or with Databinding to a dependency property

The XAML of my UserControl:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="155">
    <TextBox x:Name="TB_Date" LostFocus="TB_Date_LostFocus" KeyDown="TB_Date_KeyDown" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="125" Height="24">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <VisualBrush x:Name="VisuBrush" x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Label x:Name="L_Watermark" Content="{Binding Watermark, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=Date}" Foreground="LightGray" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    <DatePicker Name="DP_Date" Focusable="False" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectedDateChanged="DP_Date_SelectedDateChanged" Width="30" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Height="24"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the eventhandler in which i want to set the `Content` property of the `L_Watermark` label

```
 private void Initialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HasStartTime)
        {
            TB_Date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(); 
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(Watermark);
    }
```

Like the `Text` in `TB_Date` i tried to to it with `L_Watermark.Content = Watermark`

I also tried to do it with Databinding like:

```
<Label x:Name="L_Watermark" Content="{Binding Watermark, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=Date}" Foreground="LightGray" />
```

I also have two dependency properties in my UserControl:

```
public bool HasStartTime
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(HasStartTimeProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(HasStartTimeProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasStartTime.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HasStartTimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HasStartTime", typeof(bool), typeof(AdvancedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(false));

public string Watermark
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(WatermarkProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Watermark.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(AdvancedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata("Datum"));
```

Comment: You want to set a property to a dependency property of *what*? At least show us what you tried. "Nothing work" isn't specific enough to guess what you did wrong. Show us how you tried "about his name". Show us your XAML or your C# code for "about his name". Is this in a ControlTemplate or a DataTemplate? What does it belong to?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do. But you've created a resouce called `VisuBrush`. What did you want to do with it?

Comment: Now i updated the post. I hope now it is more clear what my problem is.

Comment: As a note, you don't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event for dependency properties. They provide their own change notification mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will remove it. But the is problem is also alive.